# Error with Create Custum Template in Jama

Tags: templates

I have an error while using Jama software to create a custom report template.
One resource is the Jama User Guide: http://help.jamasoftware.com/
 Custom Report Development->Office Template Reports ->Building Custom Office Export Templates
The above page in the jama support webpage explains the process.
This guide directs to open the Export button, click 'Upload Template', and then browse the computer for the file.  Any file selected for upload give sthe following error:

Unable to get property 'getValue' of undefined or null reference

I have downloaded the original Word Template and attempted to upload it again unchanged, but get the same error.  This makes me assume that the template files are valid, but something is perhaps wrong with the upload process.
On various websites, I have seen other questions with the same error, but none on the Jama software specifically, and none with a solution that I was able to apply.

My question is what does this error mean, and how to upload a valid report to Jama.
Thanks
[Image 1 shows Error message with Choose Template page in background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtiMR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that you try to call `getValue` of a `null` object, so search for

> .getValue

and check out which objects are `null`. If you have `foo.getValue()`, then there is a chance that `foo` is `null`. Make sure that it is either not `null`, or you do not call its `getValue` if it is `null` or you properly handle the error potentially arising from the case.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a permissions issue.  The permissions weren't set up yet, so Jama apparently submitted a null value in place of the intended file.